# Tomiko's "new exercise" for Saki

Tags: from-the-new-world

Shortly after Tomiko defended Saki in court, Tomiko escorted Saki to the pier where she would set off. Tomiko mentioned that after Saki's return, she would be given a "new exercise" for her Cantus, which allegedly would be more interesting than routine classroom exercises. What was that exercise?

Comment: Telomere extension/restoration?

Comment: I conjectured that at first, but no more of it was mentioned; would they have at least indicated at the end that Saki could lengthen her lifespan? Otherwise, there is no proof; I am looking for such proof, possibly from the novel.

Comment: In the chapter 12 of manga adaptation, it is suggested that telomere restoration is an ability instead of a skill. Not sure how faithful the manga/anime are to the novel, since the manga and anime have quite a number of differences.